# Envoy proxy memory usage spikes on service deployments

Tags: envoyproxy

Using envoy as a proxy for our services. The envoy proxy is running inside a Kubernetes pod along with a service which acts as its control plane. All our services also run in Kubernetes and this envoy proxy acts as an ingress.

Facing memory usage spikes in the pods where envoy proxy was running. This was happening whenever a new pod of any service was getting added or deleted.

[image: Envoy memory usage]

[image: Envoy Logs]

On deeper analysis, I found out that we were updating our envoy config, for every pod addition/removal, which caused these memory spikes.

I did some research and found out that instead of updating the whole config we can just update the Delta. [Envoy Documentation](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/overview/xds_api#delta-endpoints)

After making these changes, here is what our config looks like (some part of it):

```
    "dynamic_resources": {
     "lds_config": {
      "api_config_source": {
       "api_type": "DELTA_GRPC",
       "grpc_services": [
        {
         "envoy_grpc": {
          "cluster_name": "metadata_service_xds"
         }
        }
       ],
       "transport_api_version": "V3"
      },
      "resource_api_version": "V3"
     },
     "cds_config": {
      "api_config_source": {
       "api_type": "DELTA_GRPC",
       "grpc_services": [
        {
         "envoy_grpc": {
          "cluster_name": "metadata_service_xds"
         }
        }
       ],
       "transport_api_version": "V3"
      },
      "resource_api_version": "V3"
     }
    },
    "admin": {
     "access_log_path": "/tmp/admin_access.log",
     "address": {
      "socket_address": {
       "address": "0.0.0.0",
       "port_value": 9901
      }
     }
    }
   },
```

Now in the envoy logs I can see that we are not updating all the clusters every time a new pod gets added, but I can see that the listeners still gets updated. Could anyone please help me if I am missing something?

[image: Envoy logs after using DELTA_GRPC]

We have a lot of filter chains for our listeners, where we use gRPC JSON Transcoder. Is there a way to selectively update the listener filter chains?

Comment: related: https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/30986

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue.

I implemented a fix on the similar lines of what is mentioned in this [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=34&v=rdJZk6k314k&feature=youtu.be).

We have a bunch of gRPC JSON transcoder filters configured for one of the listeners in envoy. We use these for an internal tool.

Before triggering an update to the Envoy configuration, I sorted the gRPC JSON transcoder filters according to the service name. This approach appears to have resolved the spikes in memory usage. Instead of observing the addition of new listeners and the draining of old ones with every deployment, I now notice these changes only when there is an actual modification in the proto descriptor (which I think is expected). More details [here](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/30986).